# Problem with Qualcomm Wireless Adapter with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, wireless, atheros, ubuntu-drivers

Here is the dmesg log.

```
sank3th@sank3th-Lenovo-Z51-70:~$ dmesg | grep ath10k
[    8.058621] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: pci irq msi-x interrupts 8 irq_mode 
0 reset_mode 0
[    8.297037] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal- 
pci-0000:03:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[    8.368033] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for             
ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/board-2.bin failed with error -2
[    9.518435] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: firmware crashed! (uuid n/a)
[    9.518455] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: qca6164 hw2.1 (0x05010000, 
0x003405ff sub 17aa:3545) fw WLAN.RM.1.1-00141 fwapi 5 bdapi 1 htt-ver 0.0 
wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1 features ignore- 
otp,no-4addr-pad
[    9.518461] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: debug 0 debugfs 0 tracing 0 dfs 0 
testmode 0
[    9.520971] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: firmware register dump:
[    9.520975] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: [00]: 0x05010000 0x000015B3 
0x000A012D 0x00955B31
[    9.520988] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: [04]: 0x000A012D 0x00060330 
0x00000016 0x88805006
[    9.520990] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: [08]: 0x00000000 0x00400000 
0x00400600 0x00000001
[    9.520993] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: [12]: 0x00000009 0x00000000 
0x00931C61 0x00931C7D
[    9.520995] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: [16]: 0x0096BDBC 0x009287BD 
0x00000000 0x00000000
[    9.521001] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: [20]: 0x400A012D 0x0040E2B0 
0x00955A00 0x00404590
[    9.521005] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: [24]: 0x809287D9 0x0040E310 
0x7A5088F8 0xC00A012D
[    9.521009] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: [28]: 0x809288D7 0x0040E340 
0x00000000 0xFFF08040
[    9.521011] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: [32]: 0x809290FE 0x0040E360 
0x00400000 0x00400600
[    9.521014] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: [36]: 0x80929205 0x0040E380 
0x00000000 0x00400600
[    9.521017] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: [40]: 0x40928024 0x0040E3B0 
0x0040D3D0 0x0040D3D0
[    9.521020] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: [44]: 0x00000000 0x0040E3D0 
0x009BB001 0x00040020
[    9.521022] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: [48]: 0x00401BF0 0x00000001 
0x00404B9C 0x00400000
[    9.521025] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: [52]: 0x40928024 0x0040E3B0 
0x0040D3D0 0x0040D3D0
[    9.521027] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: [56]: 0x24F53000 0x0574E757 
0xCBBCB040 0xF8B5FDDF
[   10.515562] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: failed to receive control response 
completion, polling..
[   11.515679] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: ctl_resp never came in (-110)
[   11.515685] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: failed to connect to HTC: -110
[   11.585740] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not init core (-110)
[   11.585782] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not probe fw (-110)
[   11.599828] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: cannot restart a device that hasn't 
been started
```

Answer (score 0):

> ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: firmware crashed! (uuid n/a)

I suggest that you update the firmware. With a temporary working internet connection by ethernet, tethering or whatever means possible, open a terminal and do:

```
cd /tmp
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.169.1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
```

Reboot and tell us if there is any improvement:

```
dmesg | grep ath
```